# Handles, Crosshandles, Crosscaps and Co

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

are there some fans of funny and challenging topology exercises?!
For now i proved the following:

- A Klein Bottle is homeomorphic to the union of two Möbiusstrips along their boundaries
- A crosshandle (or twisted handle) is homeomorphic to two crosscaps

For the first proof there is no problem (in addition there is a proof given here "[Klein-bottle and Möbius-strip together with a homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314977/klein-bottle-and-mobius-strip-together-with-a-homeomorphism)" but you can do this proof on many different ways). For the second proof i supposed $X$ to be the sphere with a crosshandle and $Y$ to be the sphere with two crosscaps. Then i made a homeomorphism $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ (because you can give arguments that both spaces are Klein-bottles). **Is there someone who can give good arguments herefore?** (i also will give my own arguments if someone is asking).

But now i want to prove that the **a crosscap with a handle is homeomorphic to three crosscaps (or in other words: i want to give a proof of Dyck's Theorem (true?!)**
Can i use the facts above?? Can someone help me with this construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the paper [Conway's ZIP Proof](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/francisweeks.pdf) by G. Francis & J. Weeks.
If I remember correctly, everything you're looking for is nicely described in there.

Comment: Okay thanks :) Maybe it is the best idea to read the script and figure out what is important for the exercise.

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @BenMillwood : Thank you, I fixed the link.